# Trigger Quasar QBtn click using vue-test-utils / jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, quasar-framework, vue-test-utils, quasar

I am trying to simulate a button click of a quasar QBtn component in Jest(using vue-test-utils).
I need to test if the @click method gets called when the button is clicked so I did the following

```
  it("Expects createAccount to be called", async () => {
    const button = wrapper.findComponent(QBtn);
    await button.trigger('click');

    expect(methods.createAccount).toBeCalled();
  })
```

And I also mocked `createAccount` function using `jest.fn()`
But I always get 0 calls of the function, although it works if I directly use

```
wrapper.vm.createAccount()
```

And just check if the function got called...
Any ideas how I can trigger the click event on the QBtn? I also tried using `find('button')` and triggering click, did not work either

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way  Hope it helps.

```
  it("expects createAccount to be called when button is clicked", async () => {
    // Arrange
    const button = wrapper.find('BUTTON CLASS NAME');
    const createAccount = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'createAccount');

    // Action
    await button.trigger('click');
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    // Assert
    expect(createAccount).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

For those types of tests, I use [cypress](https://github.com/W3AS/quasar-cypress-example); personnaly I prefer to use jest to test methods, computed, etc...